# Prevent iframe from being redirected to identical adress

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, if-statement, iframe

I want to prevent an iframe from being redirected to the same adress that's currently loaded inside of it. The reason I want to do this is because I want to prevent the unnecessary white flicker when you're redirected to the exact same page.

Here's a jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/8zs8mh5d/

```
<a href="http://www.randomwebsite.com/" target="tc">dont redirect if not from link 3</a><br>

<a href="http://www.randomwebsite.com/" target="tc">dont redirect if not from link 3</a><br>

<a href="http://day.smakkie.com/" target="tc">dont redirect if not from link 1 or 2</a><br>

<iframe id="truecontent" name="tc" src="http://www.randomwebsite.com/"></iframe>



#truecontent
{
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JavaScript like:

```
 function confirmTarget(target) {
  current = document.getElementById('truecontent').getAttribute('src');
  if(current != target)
   document.getElementById('truecontent').src = target;
 }
```

And modify your links like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="confirmTarget('http://www.randomwebsite.com/')">dont redirect if not from link 3</a><br />
<a href="#" onclick="confirmTarget('http://www.randomwebsite.com/')">dont redirect if not from link 3</a><br />
<a href="#" onclick="confirmTarget('http://day.smakkie.com/')">dont redirect if not from link 1 or 2</a><br />
```

Here's a JSFiddle with it: http://jsfiddle.net/5xs3tnze/2/

Answer (score 0):

You may need a little JavaScript help for that. Define your links like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="redirectIframe('http://www.randomwebsite.com/', 'tc')">dont redirect if not from link 3</a><br>

<a href="#" onclick="redirectIframe('http://www.randomwebsite.com/', 'tc')">dont redirect if not from link 3</a><br>

<a href="#" onclick="redirectIframe('http://day.smakkie.com/', 'tc')">dont redirect if not from link 3</a><br>

<br>

<iframe id="truecontent" name="tc" src="http://www.randomwebsite.com/"></iframe>
```

Then add a redirect function

```
function redirectIframe(url,name) {
    var iFrame = document.getElementsByName(name)[0];

    if (iFrame.src != url) iFrame.src = url;
}
```

function will check if URL you're redirecting to is the same as current IFRAME source and if that's the case return without redirection.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8zs8mh5d/1/